# Calculating velocity from pressure and density works with SI units, but not with imperial units

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity, units

I have the following formula (taken from https://calculator.academy/pressure-to-velocity-calculator/) to calculate the velocity of a fluid knowing it's pressure and density:
$$
V = \sqrt {2Q÷\rho}
$$
with V being the velocity in m/s, Q the pressure in Pascal and $\rho$ the density in kg/m<sup>3</sup>. If I use these units, I get the same results on my pocket calculator as in the online calculator. If I however change the units in the online calculator to ft/s, PSF and lb/ft<sup>3</sup> and enter for example 1000 PSF as the pressure and 5 lbs/ft<sup>3</sup> as the density, I get ~113.44 ft/s in the online calculator, but using the above formula I get 20 as result - why, and what unit would that be if I divide PSF by lb/ft<sup>3</sup> ? And if I used PSI and lbs/in<sup>3</sup> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the pound is, in fact, a unit of force, not a unit of mass.

The website implicitly converts between pounds and slugs (slug being the Imperial unit of mass) using Earth's acceleration due to gravity.

We have 32.17 lbs. = 1 slug.
We can get this from F = m*g, where F is in pounds, m is the mass in slugs, and g is acceleration due to gravity, in feet/s$^2$.
Acceleration due to gravity is 32.17 feet/s$^2$ in Imperial units.

By this conversion, we have a density of 0.15542 slugs/ft$^3$.

You can then use this as your density and return the answer that the website gave you.

Comment: For ft / PSF this was the problem indeed, but how about pounds per cubic inch / PSI ? I tried selecting 1000 PSI, 5 lb/in^3 and ft/s in the online calculator then multiplied the result with 12 to get ~1361.28 in/s, but using 1000 PSI and 0.15542 slugs/in^3 with the formula I again got a completely different result of  ~287.754 …

Comment: If for the PSI / lb/in^3 variant I multiply the density (0.15542 slugs/ft^3) by 12 (ft to in conversion factor), I get the right result - can you explain that to me ?

Comment: If I do $V = \sqrt {2 \cdot 1000 PSI ÷ 0.15542 slugs/in^3} \cdot \sqrt {12}$ I also get the right result ?

Comment: And also when I do $V = \sqrt {2 \cdot 1000 PSI \cdot 12 ÷ 0.15542 slugs/in^3}$, which essentially converts PSI (lbf / in^2) to … lbf / in^3 ??